# Hell yeah! - How to express great joy?

Tags: translation

I'm looking for some exclamations to be used in comics to express great joy and pride, such as:

- "I'm a good boy!",
- "Hell yeah!",
- "I'm so great!"

or similar. Any suggestion?

Comment: 好极了！ Great! 那真好极了！ That's really cool! 好棒啊！/太棒了！ Terrific!

Comment: @ Drunken Master: Nice! Any suggestion for something to be written on a T-shirt, like "I'm so cool!", "I'm so wonderful!"?
Would you post your thoughts in an answer, so that I can accept it and give you reputation?

Comment: @DrunkenMaster Indeed, 好极了 can be seen in many books, can be heard in foreign movies or shows dubbed into Chinese, but I've never heard that in real life, maybe because it sounds a little bookish. 好棒啊！/太棒了！would be more common.

Comment: I believe that, due to the little readiness of Chinese people to openly brag about themselves, the answer should greatly vary with context.

Comment: @Stan "好极了" returns ~4.6 million results on Google, Baidu returns ~29.7 million, I think it's quite OK to use it, not "bookish" at all.

Comment: @DrunkenMaster not a surprise there're many results on Google. As my last comment mentioned, 好极了 is widely used in some situations (including manga books, of course). But for expressing **great joy and pride** (by bookish, I meant the character 了 is difficult to be shouted out aloud), I do observe very few samples in real life :) I just wanted to clarify this point.

Comment: **倍儿棒**, I'm not sure how *cringeworthy* this is now but there you have it.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what dialect you're writing in. For example, Cantonese (primarily used in Hong Kong) has slang versions that is different from Mandarin.

In Mandarin

**I'm a good boy**
乖仔 (this is in cantonese and is a slang). It means, "Good boy!"
我很聽話 (this is universal). It literally means, "I listen." But it in practice means, "I'm well behaved."

**Hell yeah:** 
棒死了 (this means "fresh to death!")
The important word is "棒", which means "awesome."
Alternatively, some people use "酷" as a slang. This literally means "Cool" and sounds like "cool" in Chinese.

**I so great**
我好勁 
The important word is "勁," which means "strength" or "great"
This is slang term. But if someone read this, they would laugh.

Answer (score 3):

It depends if you want to use some formal words or not.

informal (but normally stronger than formal words). I think it is OK to use these words in comics:

爽 or 爽翻了

牛B

活活美死

Answer (score 2):

One of the current trending slang for "great" is “碉堡了” or “叼炸天”。
For a less extreme expression you can use “给力”。

So for example to express "I am so great!": 我碉堡了。
"Hell yeah!": 给力！

Answer (score 2):

It just strikes me to write a Python program to generate some possible translations because there are so many possible ways of saying this.

```
# the subject I (optional)
Im = ['', '我']

# the adverb 'so'
so = ['超', '超级', '真', '真的', '非常', '好', '很']

# slang (optional)
fucking = ['', '他妈']

# the adjective "great"
great = ['棒', '厉害', '强', '牛', '牛逼', '给力', '伟大', '优秀', '屌']
# 屌 is actually another slang, which is sometimes written as 吊

# the modal particle as ending (optional)
ending = ['啊', '哦', '的'] 
# 的 is actually not a modal particle
# I don't know how to explain this but it is often used at the end

for subject in Im:
    for adverb in so:
        for slang in fucking:
            for adjective in great:
                for end in ending:
                    print (subject+adverb+slang+adjective+end)
```

The result looks like this:

```
......
我超他妈优秀哦
我超他妈优秀的
我超他妈屌啊
我超他妈屌哦
我超他妈屌的
我真棒啊
我真棒哦
我真棒的
......
我很他妈棒的
我很他妈厉害啊
我很他妈厉害哦
我很他妈厉害的
我很他妈强啊
我很他妈强哦
......
```

However, some of them would seem unnatural, and there are certainly a lot more ways of expressing the same feeling, especially if you dig into the deep mysterious dialects.

This answer is just for reference and fun. :D

Answer (score 1):

Warning, these are Internet slang.

> 必须的: supposed to be

A: You are so great.

B: 必须的.

> 没毛病: no shortcoming

A: Let's...

B: 没毛病/必须的